# iOS Storyboard Unsupported configuration

Tags: iphone, ios7, ios6, storyboard

I have a lot of Nagivation Items in my storyboard and I have this warning

> Plain Style unsupported in a Navigation Item

Any idea how can I find out which Navigation Item is the source of this warning in the storyboard?  Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Plain Style unsupported in a Navigation Item" warning with my customized Bar Button Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945859/plain-style-unsupported-in-a-navigation-item-warning-with-my-customized-bar-bu)