# Xcode incorrectly binding Storyboard elements to Exit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9

Developing in Xcode 9.3 Beta 2, had some issues with with `BarButtonItem` ([fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24564996)), but then got some crashes. So removed then re-added the logout button, but drag-and-dropping gives me this callout:

[image]

Setting the type to UIButton and name to `logoutPressed`, but that didn't work:
[image]

More info:
[image]

EDIT: Traced it down to wrong `ViewController` binding. But checking `tableViewController` in XML, and it has the correct `customClass` and `customModule` set. Same on the GUI. How do I rebind?

#### How do I get drag-and-drop component binding working again? - Or alternatively: how do I manually bind in XML?

Comment: Any solution yet

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, launch Xcode 9.2, copy everything from your old storyboard file to a new one, delete the old one, rename the new one Main.storyboard, that fixed it for me

Make sure you drag to the right class file

Comment: Yeah I eventually did that, but kept a copy of my old version on my HDD. In fact, I manually recreated all the views and buttons & whatnot; starting from a new Xcode project (copying over just my .swift files). Not going to accept your answer, going to wait for someone to tell me how to actually debug the .storyboard. Thanks though